# Make an alias for find command handles glob

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want to use this alias for all files that end with .txt

```
$ f "*.txt"
```

I expect to get all files that end with txt like foo.txt and bar.txt, not a file called "*.txt"
The problem is that this command is this searching for files called "*.txt" not count * as a glob.

my .bashrc:

```sh
#f
f() {
    sudo find . -name "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep --color=always $1
}

# F
F() {
    sudo find / -name "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep --color=always $1
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do.  If, for instance, you run `f '*.txt'` and `find` outputs `./a/b/c.txt`, which part of the output do you want coloured.  (Possibilities that come to mind are the whole line, `/c.txt`, `c.txt`, or `.txt`.)

Comment: @pjh Not sure if this is clean code, but this works for me anyways, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135208/5688267 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shell glob syntax and regexes are two different syntaxes. You can't use them interchangeably.

Fortunately, you don't need to get `grep` involved.

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

will find all the files that end in .txt.  If you want to exclude `.txt` then change your glob pattern to require at least one character.

```
find . -name '?*.txt'
```

Side note: Putting `sudo` in a shell alias is a bad idea. You only want to run `sudo` when you specifically ask for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, right, I mean shell glob. that is work find, I want to make an alias that's act like this. I'm using grep for coloring try 'find . -name '*.txt' | grep --color=always "*.txt"`, I will remove sudo, thank you